# Docker Jenkins Integration with Bitbucket Permission Issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, docker, jenkins, bitbucket

I have an issue accessing my bitbucket repository via my Jenkins Pipeline script. I do get an output on the Jenkins console saying that I don't have permissions to access the directory /home/ec2-user/Son-Grafana/BitBucket-Repo/observable/Soc BUT It allows me to access this directory --> /var/lib/jenkins and to use the git command inside.

I have a Jenkins server that runs as a Docker container on an AWS EC2 instance which was spinned up using a docker-compose file. On the AWS EC2 instance I cloned my bitbucket repository called /home/ec2-user/Son-Grafana/BitBucket-Repo/observable/Soc and I have always been able push new configs from the server by making commits and Pull requests so this works fine(I already configured the ec2 connection and bitbucket)

**Docker-compose**

```
    services:
  jenkins:
    container_name: ops_jenkins_server
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - /opt/jenkins_container_volume:/var 
      - /home/ec2-user/Sona-Grafana/BitBucket-Repo/observability/soc-poc:/var/lib/jenkins  
    environment:
      - JENKINS_OPTS="--httpPort=8080"
      - JAVA_OPTS="-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false"

  docker:
    image: docker:latest
    privileged: true
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

volumes:
  jenkins_home:

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

On the Bitbucket User Interface I cloned the /home/ec2-user/Son-Grafana/BitBucket-Repo/observable/Soc repository into my workspace called Emmanuel-Sona where I created a repository /home/ec2-user/Son-Grafana/BitBucket-Repo/observable/Soc-Jenkins. I generated the App-Password(Bitbucket), PrivateKey(On the Ec2 Instance), Bitbucket Oauth consumers(Bitbucket) so there is a communication between the Bitbucket and Jenkins server.

My issue now is that when I try to write a pipeline script that will cd into the main directory /home/ec2-user/Son-Grafana/BitBucket-Repo/observable/Soc  it tells me that I don't have the permissions to access the directory but when I change the directory to cd /var/lib/jenkins/test it logs smoothly and tell me the git status

**Pipeline Script**

```
pipeline {
agent any

stages {
    stage('Checkout Git Repository') {
        steps {
            // Set up the checkout directory
            sh 'cd /var/lib/jenkins/test'
            sh 'git status'
            sh 'ls -la /var/lib/jenkins'

            // Check out the current branch of the Git repository
            dir('/home/ec2-user/Sona-Grafana/BitBucket-Repo/observability/soc-poc') {
                git url: 'https://Emmanuel-Sona@bitbucket.org/emmanuel-sona/soc-jenkins.git'
            }
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeVpt.png)

[image]